# header file for usb_serial_register function?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver

I can't find header file for `usb_serial_register()` function in Linux kernel. It says:

> implicit function declaration

All members of `usb_serial_struct()` are also undeclared when doing `make`.

Comment: Please post your code so we can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Linux 4.3, [`usb_serial_register_drivers` is defined in `linux/usb/serial.h`.](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.3/include/linux/usb/serial.h#L299) The same file also defines `struct usb_serial`, `struct usb_serial_port`, and `struct usb_serial_driver`; I'm not sure which one of those you mean by "usb_serial_struct", but it's probably one of those three.